# 404 redirect when directory not found

Tags: asp.net, redirect, http-status-code-404

I need to redirect to my generic errorpage, when a users tries to access a directory that doesn't exist. I set up the following in my web.config:
    `<system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="errorpages/404.htm">
        </customErrors>
    </system.web>`

It works like a charm when I access a file that does not exist (eg. xyc.com/does_not_exist.aspx) but when I access a folder that does not exist (eg. xyz.com/does_not_exist) then I get a normal 404 instead of the generic errorpage.

What am I missing?

Best regards,
Steffen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to:

```
  <system.web>
     <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/errorpages/404.htm" />
  </system.web>
```

`~/` specifies from root directory

Comment: Awesome! I can't believe it was so simple. Thanks a bunch Curt!

Answer (score 3):

Bull whack, it makes no difference